# Showing just the (full) filenames that were changed in a revision

Tags: git

`git show` shows me all the changes made in a revision. However, it prints out all the changes - not just the file names. `git show --stat` shows me just file names, but it cuts them off! Is there anyway to just get a complete list of the filenames that were changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you have to do the grep and the cut as when given in the other answer when git can provide it to you straight ( and you don't have to depend on the output being same in later versions):

```
git log --name-only --pretty=format: -1
```

or

```
git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD^
```

You can do the same for any revision / commit that you want.

Comment: One minor issue with the `git log` command you show is that includes an extra blank line at the beginning, which might confuse a script...

Comment: Strange, that works, but greping for `--name-only` in the help page finds nothing

Answer (score 1):

try

```
git log --raw -1 | grep ^\: | cut -f2
```

this will give you the full paths of the files.

Comment: Super. You also learn about `grep` and `cut`. These are useful for working with git on the command line.